# Concatenate two rows based on the same value in the next row of a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am creating a new column and trying to concatenate the rows where the column value is the same. 1 the 1st row would have the initial value in that row, second row would the value of the 1st row and 2nd row. I have been able to make it work where the column has two values, if the column has 3 or more values only two values are being concatenated in the final row.

```
data={ 'Fruit':['Apple','Apple','Mango','Mango','Mango','Watermelon'],
'Color':['Red','Green','Yellow','Green','Orange','Green']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['length']=df['Fruit'].str.len()
df['Fruit_color']=df['Fruit']+df['length'].map(lambda x: ' '*x)
df['same_fruit']=np.where(df['Fruit']!=df['Fruit'].shift(1),df['Fruit_color'],df['Fruit_color'].shift(1)+" "+df['Fruit_color]
```

Current output:

[image]

How do i get the expected output.

Below is the output that i am expecting

[image]

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Do you want the column `Fruit_color` or was it a tool to build `same_fruit` ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou it was a column built to add white spaces between the Fruit and Color.

Comment: And the column `length` ? If I find a solution without those is it better for you or do you need them ?

Comment: I need the length as well. However if you could share a solution without the lenght. I would work with it by adding it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
data={ 'Fruit':['Apple','Apple','Mango','Mango','Mango','Watermelon'],
'Color':['Red','Green','Yellow','Green','Orange','Green']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['length']=df['Fruit'].str.len()
df['Fruit_color']=df['Fruit'] + ' ' + df['Color']
df.sort_values(by=['Fruit_color'], inplace=True)


## Get the maximum of fruit occurrence
maximum = df[['Fruit', 'Color']].groupby(['Fruit']).count().max().tolist()[0]

## Iter shift as many times as the highest occurrence 
new_cols = []
for i in range(maximum):
    temporary_col = 'Fruit_' + str(i)
    df[temporary_col] = df['Fruit'].shift(i+1)

    new_col = 'new_col_' + str(i)
    df[new_col] = df['Fruit_color'].shift(i+1)

    df.loc[df[temporary_col] != df['Fruit'], new_col] = ''

    df.drop(columns=[temporary_col], axis=1, inplace=True)
    new_cols.append(new_col)

## Use this shifted columns to create `same fruit` and drop useless columns
df['same_fruit'] = df['Fruit_color']
for col in new_cols:
    df['same_fruit'] = df['same_fruit'] + ' ' +  df[col]
    df.drop(columns=[col], axis=1, inplace=True)

Out [1]:

    Fruit       Color   length  Fruit_color         same_fruit
1   Apple       Green   5       Apple Green         Apple Green
0   Apple       Red     5       Apple Red           Apple Red Apple Green
3   Mango       Green   5       Mango Green         Mango Green
4   Mango       Orange  5       Mango Orange        Mango Orange Mango Green
2   Mango       Yellow  5       Mango Yellow        Mango Yellow Mango Orange Mango Green
5   Watermelon  Green   10      Watermelon Green    Watermelon Green
```

Comment: @Ren Lyke, has this been helpful ? Are you still struggling with it ?

Comment: @ Benoit I get an error maximum = `df[['Fruit', 'Color']].groupby(['Fruit']).count().max().tolist()[0]` i get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: It works for me. If you do `type(df[['Fruit', 'Color']].groupby(['Fruit']).count().max())` do you get a Series ?

Comment: the `tolist()[0]` is here to turn a Series into an int. So try to use `type()` at different stage to see the type of your output.  You want it to be an int

Comment: sure will try that.